# Debug bitcoin protocol implementation

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, banscore

When I'm trying to send a "VERSION" message with my custom bitcoin client, I get:

```
Warning: Local node 127.0.0.1:56425 misbehaving (delta: 1)!
```

What does it mean? How do I know what exactly is wrong with my message?

Comment: Have you tried running the `bitcoind` process with the `-debug` flag? That should give you more information

Comment: The best reference would be to look at the part of the bitcoind source code where this message is produced. If you're writing your own client, you're going to want to get familiar with the bitcoind source anyway.